# How do I access the text property of a label inside a uicollectionviewcell when tapping that cell? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a a uicollectionview with two labels. I set the `cell.label1.text = "text"` using `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. Using `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` I call `println(cell.label1.text)` and expect to see `text` printed to the console, but instead it prints `label`; what shows in the Interface Builder scene. For some reason unknown to me the placeholder text showing in Interface Builder gets printed to the console, even though `text` is showing in the simulator for that particular cell.

How do I access the text property of a label inside a uicollectionviewcell by tapping that cell?

p.s. I am using Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show all the code, so I guess you're creating a new cell instead of getting the existing one so you get the default text.

That said, you shouldn't be getting the cell to get the text any way - your class is the data source so you should be getting the source data that you used to populate the cell in the first place from your data model and using that.

Comment: Thank you. Your advice worked. I needed to call `println(arrayThatCellUsedToCreateItself[indexPath.row])` instead of `println(cell.label1.text)`